# cobbler reposync error to a downstream cobbler server

Tags: python, yum

Below is a problem of doing a cobbler reposync on one of the downstream cobbler server -

Environment:
cobbler-server1  ->
cobbler-server2  ->>
cobbler-server3

Command below is doing a cobbler reposync for a selected repo:

```
[cobbler@cobbler-server3 ~]# cobbler reposync --only=anaplan-el6-x86_64
task started: 2013-06-06_181850_reposync
task started (id=Reposync, time=Thu Jun  6 18:18:50 2013)
hello, reposync
run, reposync, run!
creating: /var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/anaplan-el6-x86_64/.origin/*******-el6-x86_64.repo
running: /usr/bin/reposync -l -d --config=/var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/*******-el6-x86_64/.origin/*******-el6-x86_64.repo --repoid=*******-el6-x86_64 --download_path=/var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror -a x86_64
2.6 kB     00:00

[anaplan-el6-x86_64: 38    of 146   ] Downloading *******-glue-1.4.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm
Could not retrieve package *******-glue-1.4.0.1-1.x86_64. Error was failure: anaplan-glue-1.4.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm from *******-el6-x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
[anaplan-el6-x86_64: 41    of 146   ] Skipping existing ......
[anaplan-el6-x86_64: 46    of 146   ] Downloading *******-launchpad-1.3.9.1-1.x86_64.rpm
Could not retrieve package *******-launchpad-1.3.9.1-1.x86_64. Error was failure: *******-launchpad-1.3.9.1-1.x86_64.rpm from *******-el6-x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

received on stderr:
Exception occured: <class 'cobbler.cexceptions.CX'>
Exception value: 'cobbler reposync failed'
Exception Info:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/utils.py", line 132, in die
    raise CX(msg)

Exception occured: <class 'cobbler.cexceptions.CX'>
Exception value: 'cobbler reposync failed'
Exception Info:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/action_reposync.py", line 125, in run
    self.sync(repo)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/action_reposync.py", line 169, in sync
    return self.yum_sync(repo)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/action_reposync.py", line 402, in yum_sync
    utils.die(self.logger,"cobbler reposync failed")
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/utils.py", line 140, in die
    raise CX(msg)

reposync failed, tries left: 0
reposync failed, retry limit reached, skipping
running: chown -R root:apache /var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/*******-el6-x86_64
received on stdout:
received on stderr:
running: chmod -R 755 /var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/*******-el6-x86_64
received on stdout:
received on stderr:
Exception occured: <class 'cobbler.cexceptions.CX'>
Exception value: 'overall reposync failed, at least one repo failed to synchronize'
Exception Info:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/utils.py", line 132, in die
    raise CX(msg)

Exception occured: <class 'cobbler.cexceptions.CX'>
Exception value: 'overall reposync failed, at least one repo failed to synchronize'
Exception Info:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/remote.py", line 89, in run
    rc = self._run(self)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/remote.py", line 248, in runner
    3), name=name, nofail=nofail, logger=self.logger)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/api.py", line 799, in reposync
    return reposync.run(name)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/action_reposync.py", line 154, in run
    utils.die(self.logger,"overall reposync failed, at least one repo failed to synchronize")
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/utils.py", line 140, in die
    raise CX(msg)

!!! TASK FAILED !!!
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue,

Delete the packages that produced the error -

```
    [anaplan-el6-x86_64: 38    of 146   ] Downloading *******-glue-1.4.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm
    Could not retrieve package *******-glue-1.4.0.1-1.x86_64. Error was failure: anaplan-glue-1.4.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm from
*******-el6-x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
    [anaplan-el6-x86_64: 41    of 146   ] Skipping existing ......
    [anaplan-el6-x86_64: 46    of 146   ] Downloading *******-launchpad-1.3.9.1-1.x86_64.rpm
    Could not retrieve package *******-launchpad-1.3.9.1-1.x86_64. Error was failure: *******-launchpad-1.3.9.1-1.x86_64.rpm from
*******-el6-x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

ex.

```
 rm -rf /var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/anaplan-el6-x86_64/anaplan-launchpad-1.3.9.1-1.x86_64.rpm
 rm -rf /var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/anaplan-el6-x86_64/anaplan-launchpad-1.3.9.1-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Then run the cobbler reposync command again.